# SAS - merging two data sets?

Tags: merge, sas

I have two different data set. One is patients' enrollment information, and one is their patient history, in terms of their diagnoses. The enrollment file has information for all patients (4+ million ppl) while the patient history has only about 55,000, which is because it is limited by certain diseases.

I would like to create a new data set of patient enrollment information just for thsoe patients with the specific diagnoses. Each patient has a unique patient ID, but I'm not sure whether to join, merge, etc.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Example of patient enrollment data:

 Patient ID   | Months enrolled

  1   | 60

 2 | 48

 3 | 49

Example of patient history
Patient ID | Diag1 | Diag2 | Diag3

1 | 629 |635| 646

6 | 631 | 636 | 645

7   647 | 645 | 545

Comment: Could be a merge, or join, or etc. : )  Suggest you show an example of 5 patient records, 10 patient history records, and what you would want as the output.  Also, suggest you show what you've tried, and why you were unhappy with your result.

Comment: Can you post the expected/output dataset as well? What do you mean by "those patients with the specific diagonoses"?

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to do it.  I would go the PROC SQL way:

```
proc sql;
create table MyOutput as
    select a.PatientID, a.Months, b.Diag1, b.Diag2, b.Diag3
    from Enrollment as a inner join History as b
    on a.PatientID=b.PatientID
    where b.Diag1='645' or b.Diag2='645' or b.Diag3='645'
;
quit;
```

You get the idea.

Comment: I think patient history is already filtered by diagnosis so you don't need a where clause in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge using condition.

```
data new;
merge enrollment(in=a) history(in=b);
by PatientID;
if(b);
run;
```

This will give you the result:

Patient ID | **Months enrolled** | Diag1 | Diag2 | Diag3
1 | **60** | 629 |635| 646

6 | **.** |631 | 636 | 645

7 | **.** |647 | 645 | 545

However if you want only Patient ID "1" in the result, then you have to slightly modify the above code

```
data new;
merge enrollment(in=a) history(in=b);
by PatientID;
if(a and b);
run;
```

This code will give you the result

Patient ID | **Months enrolled** | Diag1 | Diag2 | Diag3
1 | **60** | 629 |635| 646

Answer (score 0):

You can select the data you want from patient enrollment data by filtering on only the ID's that are in the Patient History Data. This can be done via a SQL Where clause that checks if the ID is in the table.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select * 
from patient_enrollment
where patient_ID in (select patient_ID from patient_history)
order by patient_ID;
quit;
```